# How to execute a JavaScript file on local machine?

Tags: javascript

I am having issues getting my JavaScript to run on my local machine and I am not using Node.js, I am looking for a way to run the JavaScript code with setting up a VM with a webserver etc. But if that is needed I will. Is it possible to run the JavaScript file without a webserver?

Comment: save `.js` file, open HTML file that includes that `.js` file

Comment: You can run it in a web browser, just use an html that has an import to the script you're using. You can view execution in the browser console.

Comment: chrome / in browser...

Comment: In addition to running it in chrome/browser, if you install node, you can just run the js file from the command line with `node filename.js`. You don't need to run node as a web server.

Comment: There is post on SuperUser that might help: [Is there a way to run Javascript without a browser, like a shell or batch script?](https://superuser.com/q/946244).

Comment: If you are on on Windows you can also use `cscript`/`wscript` https://superuser.com/questions/488763/how-to-run-js-file-from-a-command-line-on-windows. Just be warned that the in-built Windows JScript support is quite dated by today's standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it directly into a HTML file.

For that, create a simple html page, like the example below and put your script into  tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <h1>My First Heading</h1>
        <p>My first paragraph.</p>

        <script>
            alert('something'); // Js code goes here
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Put this code into any text editor and save the file as .html extension, it can be runned on any modern web browser like Chrome, Firefox or IE/Edge.

Note that the  tag pauses the page rendering till it ends the execution.

Also google jsfiddle if you need to run more complex codes.